# writing to an excel file template does not follow defined cell data formats

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi

i have an excel file whose cells have different data formats from simple currency formats `$#,##0.00 ($1,200.00)` to more complex ones.

the problem is that when i write to these cells, the formats are not followed. so if i enter a value to a currency-formatted cell, the value shows up without the formatting:

ex: 
  i entered `1234`. what i expect is `$1,234.00` (as defined in the excel cell). what i get is still `1234`

during my attempts i even tried to apply the cell's own format to itself

this is the code im using:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream inp = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/MyExcel.xlsx");

Workbook wbTemp = new XSSFWorkbook(inp);    
Sheet wbTempSheet = wbTemp.getSheetAt(0);

Cell targetCell = wbTempSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
targetCell.setCellValue(request.getParameter("myNumber"));

//i even tried reapplying the cell's own format to itself
CellStyle cs = targetCell.getCellStyle();
String df = cs.getDataFormatString();
System.out.println(df);
cs.setDataFormat(wbTemp.createDataFormat().getFormat(df));
targetCell.setCellStyle(cs);
```

upon checking the excel file i noticed that the formats were indeed implemented. however i needed to press **tab** per cell to see it take effect. is there an alternative or at least a way to simulate the tab action so that the cells are formatted upon opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found what's wrong. its this line:
`targetCell.setCellValue(request.getParameter("myNumber"));`

it should be:
`targetCell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble (request.getParameter("myNumber") ));`

forgot that numeric excel cells to be properly formatted as must be passed doubles.